# Borrowing a borrowed mutable type

Tags: rust

How can a function with a borrowed mutable reference call a second function with the same borrowed mutatble reference?

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut a = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
    
    first_function(&mut a);
    
    println!("{:?}", a);
}

fn first_function(a: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    println!("...first function");
    a[0] = 5;
    second_function(&mut a);
}

fn second_function(a: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    println!("...second function");
    a[2] = 6;
}
```

The compiler errors are normally very helpful, but I don't understand this one;

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `a` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:12:21
   |
9  | fn first_function(a: &mut Vec<i32>) {
   |                   - help: consider changing this to be mutable: `mut a`
...
12 |     second_function(&mut a);
   |                     ^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

... here's a link to the code in [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=86b14d3eb9dc047aaff5f9cf63b844ba)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By writing `&mut a`, you’re trying to take a mutable reference to `a`, not to what its value references – it would be a `&mut &mut Vec<i32>`. `a`’s value is already the mutable reference you want:

```
second_function(a);
```

[updated playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aeb2a46a354f85768047573d1f0cdff8)